# condition for an input (between 2 numbers)

Tags: php

Im doing a page that contains an input that should contains 0 or 1

I did the condition to stop if the field is empty... I need a way to make a second condition that the variable added is "1" or "0" only.

```
if(empty($moviedisplay)){
    echo  "Movie display is a must";
}
```

Comment: Removed [phpmyadmin] tag as it has nothing common here.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(empty($moviedisplay) || ($moviedisplay != 0 && $moviedisplay != 1)) {
    echo  "Movie display is a must";
}
```

If you prefer different messages:

```
if(empty($moviedisplay)) {
    echo  "Movie display is a must";
}
elseif($moviedisplay != 0 && $moviedisplay != 1) {
    echo  "Movie display must be 0 or 1";
}
```

Besides that, please read the PHP docs - this is an *extremely* basic question you shouldn't have to ask here or on any other site.